# How to tell emacs to insert certain expression from line x to line y

Tags: emacs

In some of my programming, off late, I have often had to manually enter in the values of a long `std::vector`. So for a vector of size 30, I have to keep typing

```
myvec[0]=1.0;
myvec[1]=4.6;
myvec[2]=6.7;
myvec[3]=7.8;
.
.
myvec[29]=87;
```

I use Emacs as a text editor. Is it possible in Emacs for me to somehow specify that say from lines 30 to 59 insert the lines

```
myvec[0]= ;
myvec[1]= ;
myvec[2]= ;
.
.
myvec[29]= ;
```

The individual values of the vector will of course have to be manually entered, but it would save me a lot of typing or copy/pasting `myvec[]` again and again.

Comment: Incidentally, if you have those values in a file, chances are that you *don't* need to enter them manually. You could either extract them into a list and them add the rest of the code around them, or with keyboard macros you could find, copy, and paste the value as part of the macro definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Keyboard Macros](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros) is
the simpler way to do it.

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>(</kbd>`myvec[`<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd><kbd>C-i</kbd>`]
= ;`<kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>)</kbd>

- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>(</kbd> starts the macro definition
- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd><kbd>C-i</kbd>
  inserts and increments the counter
- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>)</kbd> ends the macro
  definition

And then
<kbd>M-3</kbd><kbd>M-9</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>

- <kbd>M-3</kbd><kbd>M-9</kbd> is a short cut for
  <kbd>C-u</kbd>`39` and is used to send `39` as an
  argument
- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> executes the last macro
  recorded

Thus the combination of both executes the macro 39 times.

You can also look in [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Keyboard-Macros) to see how you can [save](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Save-Keyboard-Macro) them and [edit](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Edit-Keyboard-Macro) them.

Answer (score 4):

Try this sequence (Emacs golf score=17):

<kbd><f3></kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd><f3></kbd><kbd>]</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd><kbd>;</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd><kbd>M-3</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd><f4></kbd>

Comment: Interesting: <f3> plays the double role.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with keyboard macros, but if you need this often then you may be better off with a function which can be called with M-x and asks for a string to be inserted, the start number of the sequence and the end number:

```
(defun my-insert-numbered-template (string start end)
  (interactive "sString (use %%s as a placeholder for the number) : \nnSequence start: \nnSequence end: ")
  (while (<= start end)
    (insert (format string start) "\n")
    (incf start)))
```

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>(</kbd> to start recording a keyboard macro. 
Then type in `myvec[`<kbd>F3</kbd>`] ;` and <kbd>RET</kbd> and then <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>)</kbd> to finish defining your macro.

Now, you can simply say <kbd>C-u</kbd> `29` and <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd>. It will run the macro 29 times, and the position where you hit <kbd>F3</kbd> will be filled in with the macro counter, giving you increments.

This sounds more complicated than writing a function as Tom suggested, but I'd recommend you try and master keyboard macros. The amount of work they can cut down once you get comfortable with them is truly incredible.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to do this is using regex search and replace.

First, type `myVec[]=;<ret>`.

Next, copy that entire region *including* the newline. Then paste it in as many times as necessary. Now you have a bunch of `myVec[]=;` lines.

Now select the entire region of `myVec`s and do `M-x replace-regexp` `]` `\#]` which will number it for you.

This is the real magic of Emacs--you have a bunch of powerful tools which means there is always more than one way to do it.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know this feature. It would even be better if the sequence start number could be specified somehow, though I understand it's not possible, because it's not the intended use of the feature.